Dedekind sums and signature of two-bridge knots
Let $0<q<p$ be two odd coprime numbers and set $\sigma(p,q)=\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{\lfloor \frac{nq}{p}\rfloor}$.
My question is purely number theoretic: can this sum be expressed in terms of a Dedekind sum related to the pair $(p,q)$?
For some background, this sum is the signature of the two-bridge knot $K(p,q)$: it should be related to the signature defect of its ramified double cover, the lens space $L(p,q)$, which is proportional to the corresponding Dedekind sum by a theorem of Hirzebruch. Unfortunately, I don't see how : any help is welcome!

Hi Julien! Are you asking whether there's a purely number-theoretic proof of an expression relating $\sigma(p,q)$ and a Dedekind sum involving $p$ and $q$, or are you rather asking what is the precise relationship between the two?

Hi Marco, any of the two would help me.
I believe one can find a relation between the two using previous work identifying Dedekind sums with topological invariants, however a direct proof would make me even more happy.

After some elementary computations, I found the formula $\sigma(p,q)=8s(q,2p)-4s(q,p)$ where $s(q,p)$ is the standard Dedekind sum. It would be nice to have a topological explanation but I am already happy with that.
